# SWI prolog make set of variables name with rbtrees or others means

Tags: variables, tree, prolog, set

I have got a term from which I want to get set of variables name.

Eg. input: my_m(aa,b,B,C,max(D,C),D) 
output: [B,C,D] (no need to be ordered as order of appearance  in input)
(That would call like set_variable_name(Input,Output).)

I can simply get [B,C,D,C,D] from the input, but don't know how to implement set (only one appearance in output). I've tried something like storing in rbtrees but that failed, because of

```
only_one([],T,T) :- !.
only_one([X|XS],B,C) :- rb_in(X,X,B), !, only_one(XS,B,C).
only_one([X|XS],B,C) :- rb_insert(B,X,X,U), only_one(XS,U,C).
```

it returns tree with only one node and unification like `B=C, C=D...`. I think I get it why - because of unification of X while questioning rb_in(..).

So, how to store only once that name of variable? Or is that fundamentally wrong idea because we are using logic programming? If you want to know why I need this, it's because we are asked to implement A* algorithm in Prolog and this is one part of making search space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort/2`, which also removes duplicates.

Comment: But I want to store names of variables. Did you meant it like this?
`c([],[]) :- !.
c([X|XS],C) :- c(XS,A), append(X,A,D), sort(D,C).`
try c([A,B,C,A],R). ? I want to get R=[A,B,C].

Comment: The built-in predicate `sort/2` does that. Try `?- sort([A,B,C,A], Vs).`.

Comment: You have my thanks and my sorry! It works. I wanted to try something as add if not in, because this way there is a possibility of mutiple append and then the sorting. Is there other way?

Comment: When working with variables, you have to take care not to accidentally unify them. To check for variable equality, use `==/2`. `append/3` won't do. I recommend you simply use `sort/2` or check beforehand if a variable is already in a list, using `==/2`, for example, to see if the *variable* `X` is in a list `Vs`, try `member(V, Vs), V == X.`. Notice that `X` is unified with each element in the list on backtracking if you simply aks `member(X, Vs)`.

Comment: Yea, 'cause of that. But why don't implement something already existing [term_variables/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_variables/2) :))